# Paste Special of object 'Range' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am relatively new to VBA and this is my first post. I am puzzled by this issue I'm facing with what I believe should be very simple code. The goal is to automatically copy a range of Excel formulas on different sheets one at a time and paste them into a different range of cells on the same sheet (this range varies day to day as new data comes into our system, so I defined the range in excel formula in cells A3:D3, then VBA pulls the ranges in using the "indirect" function). For me this happens in my "For Each" loop

The macro runs just fine until this line, then I get a "Method PasteSpecial of Object 'Range' failed":

`ws.Range("indirect($B$3)").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`

What's really strange is the entire Macro runs perfectly fine if I step through it with F8. As soon as I hit F5 or assign the macro to a button and try to run it all the way through? Error. Every time on the same step.

I hope its something simple and easy to fix, but thanks in advance for your help! If you need any further details from me to diagnose the issue, please let me know. Full macro is pasted below

- gr8scotttch

```
    Sub rearrangeformulas_refresh_1_2()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = Workbooks("QueryMaster_Formulas.xlsm")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Order_Data")
    
        Application.Calculation = xlManual
    
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
    
    ws.Select
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    
        ws.Range("$A$4").Select
    
        ws.Range("indirect($A$3)").Copy
        
        ws.Range("indirect($B$3)").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
        
        ws.Range("indirect($C$3)").Copy
        
        ws.Range("indirect($D$3)").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
        
        ws.Range("$A$4").Select
        
    Next ws
    
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Order_Data")
    ws.Select
    
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem, honestly. You really have ranges named `"indirect($A$3)"` and so on?

Comment: You can also get rid of those selects and the redundant activesheet assignation. Why define `ws` as a specific sheet and then use it in a loop through all sheets?

Comment: I have some formulas at the top of each sheets that use =counta() and so on to identify the ranges in which formulas need to be copied/pasted. The "indirect(A3)" just pulls the contents of those cells that summarize the ranges, rather than having to deal with multiple named ranges. Can you clarify what you mean by "XY problem"?

Comment: `ws.Range("indirect($A$3)").Copy` should maybe be `ws.Range(ws.Range("A3").Value).Copy` ?